# Alamofire - save data in stored properties

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a model class which contain some user data. The data was download from server in JSON format. I would like to parse the data and save into array.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            let data: JSON = JSON(response.2.value!)
            self.jsonData = data
}
```

but the problem is that the **jsonData** is unavailable outside of this closure.
How can I do this? I spend few hours on this problem and I do not have idea :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your own closure to request and call it in completion handler:

```
makeRequest(success: { (data: JSON) in self.jsonData = data })
func makeRequest(#success: (JSON) -> ()) {
  Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        let data: JSON = JSON(response.2.value!)
        success(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Main sense here is your closure should have access to jsonData variable. My code is just example

Comment: How can I handle if async operation is completed?

Comment: Main pattern of async operations is pass callback-function in async block. Like my 'success' function. When operation completes it will call 'success' and pass in success-function response data